# SAS/BASE sorting and flaging observations

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to prepare a transactional data. I have  Individuals and their transaction dates. I want to sort data primarly on Customer ID and  then tranaction date. Until there it is not a big challenge, but in addition to this i require to print a new variable that states oder of every transaction by number for every individual. The final data would look like the picture at the link printed bellow.

http://zeybekomer.blogspot.com.tr/2015/09/stack1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the 'first' option (dataset must be sorted first):

```
data b;
   set a;
   by customer_id;
   if First.customer_id  then count=0;
   count+1;
   run;
```

Comment: also, from the example, one thing is not clear: do you want to have the order to be counted just by customer id? in the example, row 4 should be moved to row 2 after doing a sort by customer id and date and then given a 'count' of 2, unless the sort is done differently?